# Java - Cylinder Program - Unable to use main

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, static-methods

I am so lost I don't even know what question to ask anymore. I have this program that is supposed to be able to construct a Cylinder with parameters radius and height. Then it should be able to call various methods to get and set radius as well as output surface area and volume. I can't get passed go because I cannot put anything in my main without an error about static non static methods being used in static. I don't even know what that means. I actually copy code from others into my compiler and it gives me the same error. Do I have some setting screwed up? I know this is probably too elementary for Stack Overflow but I am desperate at this point.

```
public class Miller_A03Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(1,17);
        Cylinder cylinder2 = new Cylinder(3,8);
        Cylinder cylinder3 = new Cylinder(2,12);
        Cylinder cylinder4 = new Cylinder (1,14);    
    }

    public class Cylinder{
        private double radius = 0.0;
        private double height= 0.0;
        private double area = 0.0;
        private double volume=0.0;
        private String shape = "cylinder";


        public Cylinder(double r,double h){
            this.radius = r;
            System.out.print(r);
            this.height = h;
            System.out.print(h);

        }
        public double getVolume(){
            double volume = 3.14 * radius * radius * height;
            return volume;
        }
        public double getArea(){
            double circumference = 3.14 * 2 * radius;
            double circleArea = 3.14 * radius * radius;
            double area = (2 * circleArea) + (circumference * this.height);
            return area;
        }
        public double getRadius(){
            return this.radius;
        }
        public double getHeight(){
            return this.height;
        }
        public void setHeight(double h){
            this.height = h;
        }
        public void setRadius(double r){
            this.radius = r;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return this.shape + this.radius + this.height+ this.volume + this.area;
        }            
    }       
}
```

Comment: Try `public static class Cylinder{` .... Your `Cylinder` as you defined it needs an instance of `Miller_A03Q1`.

Comment: You can also create `Miller_A03Q1` and `Cylinder` as two separated classes.

Answer (score 5):

Inner classes are just like any other member (well, except for `enum`s). If you don't explicitly declare them `static`, they won't be, so you won't be able to access them from a static context, such as `main`. To make a long story short - declare you `Cylinder` inner class as `static`, and you should be OK:

```
public class Miller_A03Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(1,17);
        Cylinder cylinder2 = new Cylinder(3,8);
        Cylinder cylinder3 = new Cylinder(2,12);
        Cylinder cylinder4 = new Cylinder (1,14);
    }

    public static class Cylinder{
        // etc...
```

Comment: I don't know you but I love you. I cannot believe that one word cause me so much grief.

Comment: @rkstm This is pretty normal when you write code. The small mistakes make the biggest trouble :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you need the outer class but if you just put the main method inside the Cylinder class it compiles for me....

```
public class Cylinder {
    private double radius = 0.0;
    private double height = 0.0;
    private double area = 0.0;
    private double volume = 0.0;
    private String shape = "cylinder";

    public Cylinder(double r, double h) {
        this.radius = r;
        System.out.print(r);
        this.height = h;
        System.out.print(h);

    }

    public double getVolume() {
        double volume = 3.14 * radius * radius * height;
        return volume;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        double circumference = 3.14 * 2 * radius;
        double circleArea = 3.14 * radius * radius;
        double area = (2 * circleArea) + (circumference * this.height);
        return area;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return this.radius;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double h) {
        this.height = h;
    }

    public void setRadius(double r) {
        this.radius = r;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.shape + this.radius + this.height + this.volume + this.area;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(1, 17);
        Cylinder cylinder2 = new Cylinder(3, 8);
        Cylinder cylinder3 = new Cylinder(2, 12);
        Cylinder cylinder4 = new Cylinder(1, 14);
    }
}
```